# Script to grep pattern in the log

Tags: bash, perl, shell

I want to write a shell script or perl script to look for the below pattern from the log:

Example pattern that I look into from the log as below:

> 2016-11-21 04:46:30,491 **http-threadID001** username 286x64823x2 **sessionID1** 10.95.41.89,129.160.54.165,127.0.0.1 /rest/issueNav/1/issueTable JQL lucene query: *:*
>
> 2016-11-21 04:46:30,492 **http-threadID001** username 286x64823x2 **sessionID1**  10.95.41.89,129.160.54.165,127.0.0.1 /rest/issueNav/1/**issueTable JQL sorts: [<"custom:"customfield_10270"**:com.atlassian.jira.issue.search.parameters.lucene.sort.DocumentSortComparatorSource@d6f17821"> ]
>
> 2016-11-21 04:46:30,492 **http-threadID001** username 286x64823x2 **sessionID1**  10.95.41.89,129.160.54.165,127.0.0.1 /rest/issueNav/1/**issueTable Lucene boolean Query:*:***

If match the pattern same http-threadID001, and same sessionID1, and with the issueTable JQL sorts:<"custom:"customfield_10270" and last with the issue Table Lucene boolean Query from the log, then it will email to support@blabla.com

This script will be set in unix crontask and probably run for every 1minutes.

Can anyone give me some idea on how to write this script? Thanks!

Comment: Are the bold parts the pattern in question?

Comment: yes, the bold parts is the patterns

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: expected output is it will send email to support with the log information contain username and the match pattern (the entire line of the log which mean the 3 line)

Comment: @HPLoh: You want those lines having all the above patterns in the same line?

Comment: Instead of bolding parts of text, use code formatting (http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) to show the *exact* input text and the output you expect, please.

Comment: @HPLoh  So, the whole text you show should be found in the log for it to match. Then, per the question "_... give me some idea on how to ..._", here is the idea.  (1) Open the file with the log.  (2a) Read the whole file into a variable (_slurp_ it), if it isn't too large, and write a regex which looks for the bolded patterns, separated by other text and newlines.  //  OR // (2b) Read the file line by line, set a flag when it runs into the first bolded pattern and then keep checking for others.  Unset the flag as suitable.  //  Can you try some of this and post what you have?

Comment: @Inian those output can in 3 separate line. The important output that we want is we can contact the person (username) and inform him/her about the sorting issue.

Comment: @HPLoh  Can you please show something that you have done or tried?

Comment: @muru sorry, i m new to this, please advise what kind of formatting for this ?

Comment: @zdim i m new on writting script. At the first time, I m just running the simple grep command as cron task, grep -i "issueTable Lucene boolean Query" logfilename and it will send email to support if able to grep the pattern. This trigger a lot false alert. After monitor the log, it seem it need to come together in the sequence as provided in my Question. I have no idea how to write yet.

Comment: @HPLoh: Please read [*How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?*](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) for information about formatting your Stack Overflow posts.

Answer (score 1):

```
 awk 'BEGIN{FS=" "}{print $0}' logfilename  |sed  -n '/http-threadID001/p; 
 /same sessionID1/p ; 
 / issueTable JQL sorts:/p; 
 /<"custom:"customfield_10270"/p; 
 /issue Table Lucene boolean Query/p'> file.tmp 

mailx -s "Subject" mailaddress <file.tmp
rm file.tmp
```

I hope this is what you need

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The Http-thread, session ID is a unknown value. Each user login will have different httpd-thread and session ID. From your answer, it look for by fix value? Thanks!

Comment: Yes it is fixed by you can change that by removing the non static parts , like(numbers after ID ) and start  /http-threadID001/p wiht ^ so it would look like this /^http-threadID/p